# Add class to all buttons with certain text

Tags: javascript

I;m trying to figure out how to add an class to all buttons with a certain text. I've got the below code working but it's only working for one button:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var isActive = document.querySelector('.btn-with-text');

    if (isActive.innerText.trim() === 'MY Custom Text') {
    document.querySelector('.btn-with-text').classList.add('btn-extra-class');
    }
</script>
```

As far as my onderstanding I should use querySelectorAll and a forEach statement, but I cannot seem to get it work.

Comment: "As far as my onderstanding I should use querySelectorAll and a forEach statement, but I cannot seem to get it work". Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Can you possibly share enough code that we can reproduce the problem you're facing (without having to guess what's going on), and therefore provide a useful response to you and others visiting in future that may have similar problems? Please, look at both "*[ask]*" and the "*[mcve]*" guidelines.

Comment: Yes, I've tried:

<script>
    var isActive = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-with-text');

        arr.forEach (isActive.innerText.trim() === 'MY Custom Text') {
        document.querySelectorAll('.btn-with-text').classList.add('btn-extra-class');
}
</script>

Comment: My apologies, I saw that code, it was in your question; but what I meant to ask for was the (relevant) HTML and CSS, so we have enough information to replicate the issue you describe, and that you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use `querySelectorAll` and loop through all elements in the array. Here is how that could happen:

```js
// Get all buttons with the class you want
var buttonsWithMyText = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-with-text');

// Loop through all buttons
buttonsWithMyText.forEach(button => {
  // Check if the text inside the button is what you search for
  if (button.innerText !== 'MY Custom Text') return;
  
  // Add the additional class you want 
  button.classList.add('btn-extra-class');
});
```

```css
/* CSS is just to showcase - it is not needed */

a, button
{
  display: block;
}

.btn-with-text,
.btn-with-text-different
{
  color: white;
}

.btn-extra-class
{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- Works with any kind of tag -->
<a href="#" class="btn-with-text">MY Custom Text</a>
<a href="#" class="btn-with-text">OTHER Custom Text</a>
<a href="#" class="btn-with-text-different">MY Custom Text</a>
<br>
<button class="btn-with-text">MY Custom Text</button>
<button class="btn-with-text">OTHER Custom Text</button>
<button class="btn-with-text-different">MY Custom Text</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly. Also because of your reply, I'm understanding javascript a bit better.

Comment: You are very welcome. Could you mark my answer as the correct one so it can get the green tick